# How to filter out columns with binary classes, that are below a specific frequency in python?

Tags: python, pandas, count, scikit-learn, multiple-columns

I am pretty new to programming, and I am sure many solutions exist, but for now, mine seems not to be working. I have a dataset with over 200 predictor variables and the majority of them are binary 1= event, 0= no event. I want to filter out all variables that have an occurrence frequency below a certain threshold, e.g., 100 times.

I've tried something like this:

```
diag = luisa.T.reset_index().rename(columns = {'index': 'diagnosis'}) 

frequency = pd.concat([diag.iloc[:,:1],pd.DataFrame(diag.sum(1))], axis = 1).rename(columns = {0:'count'}) 

frequency.nlargest(150,'count)
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the column-wise sum and filter out the columns whose sums are below a certain value, keeping in mind that the sum represents the total number of events:

```
threshold = 100

col_sum = df.sum()
filtered_df = df[col_sum[col_sum > threshold].index]
```

This will store in `filtered_df` a subset of the original `DataFrame` without those columns.

If not all your columns are binary, then you need to include the additional step of performing this operation only on the binary columns, and then reversing the condition to find the columns which do *not* fulfil your criteria:

```
binary_columns = df.isin([0, 1]).all(axis=0)
binary_df = df.loc[:, binary_columns]
col_sum = binary_df.sum()

filtered_df = df.drop(columns=col_sum[col_sum < threshold].index)
```

Comment: Oh really fast and effective, seems to be working perfectly! Thank you very much @gmds